# ValidationError at ["“<class 'datetime.timezone'>” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]

Tags: python, date, datetime, django-models

I am having trouble creating a form that saves the time that the user submits. I am receiving the following error:

````
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["“<class 'datetime.timezone'>” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]```
````

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date_and_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if post_form.is_valid():
            post = post_form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.date_and_time = str(datetime.timezone)
            post.save()
        else: 
            return render(request, "network/index.html",{
                "form": post
            })
    post_form = PostForm
    return render(request, "network/index.html",{
        "form": post_form
    })
```

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['post']
        widgets = {'post': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Create a new post here.'})
        }
```

I want to get the current date through `post.date_and_time` but am not sure how do to that. I saw some other posts on Stack Overflow using `datetime.timezone`, so I tried it but will change it if there is a better way to achieve this.

error that occurs during `python manage.py migrate`

```
File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1388, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
```

entire error message

```
WARNINGS:
network.Post: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the NetworkConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
network.User: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the NetworkConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, network, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying network.0003_post_date_and_time...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User Name\Downloads\network\project4\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\User Name\Downloads\network\project4\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 104, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 330, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 191, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 324, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 842, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1427, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1406, in get_prep_value
    value = super().get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1266, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1388, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
```

Comment: what do you expect the `post.date_and_time = str(datetime.timezone)` line to do? You're trying to pass a module to a field expecting an `datetime.datetime` or similar. Also, how's the form defined?

Comment: @Shabble, I was receiving a different error and saw on a Stack Overflow post to add ```str```; it also worked for me. Should I add the forms.py?

Comment: I don't understand what the `= datetime.timezone` line is supposed to achieve, with or without `str()` on there. Edit your question to include the Form definition from forms.py, and if possible, explain what you want that `post.date_and_time` to actually be.

Comment: @Shabble, I added the forms.py.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to change here is `post.date_and_time = timezone.now()` (where `timezone` comes from `from django.utils import timezone`.

Another option would be to change your model definition to something like:

```
date_and_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

see the [`models.DateTimeField` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) for the difference between `auto_now_add` (only on first creation) and `auto_now` (changes on each update).

Comment: I changed the code and am receiving this message ```ERRORS:
network.Post.date_and_time: (fields.E160) The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these options may be present.```. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: remove the default option :-) I think `blank=` is unnecessary as well. Check that link in my answer

Comment: I removed the ```default``` and ```blank``` and am receiving this error ```OperationalError at /
table network_post has no column named date_and_time```. I saw another post on Stack Overflow that said if you get the above error to add a default, but with a default I receive the error in my previous comment. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: that sounds more like you haven't generated or applied some migrations to your database to actually generate/update that field on your model / table. Does `./manage.py makemigrations` followed by `./manage.py migrate` help?

Comment: I have done that many times, and it does not change anything. When I run ```manage.py migrate```, I receive this message ```raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']``` in the terminal. Could this be affecting something?

Comment: is there a stack-trace around that error it prints about the ValidationError when you run migrate? Otherwise, try running it like `./manage.py migrate --traceback --verbosity 3` and share the whole output somewhere. It sounds like maybe you could have a broken migration from a previous attempt that it's failing to apply?

Comment: I added the entire validation error. There are more file messages like this one, but I do not think you would want to see all of them. When I ```runserver```, I get a message saying I have 8 unapplied migrations. I have tried makemigrations and migrate many times but nothing changes. The way you said to migrate did not change anything either.

Comment: is that the entirety of the output when running migrate? I'd have expected it to trace the other functions that ultimately call the fields.py function the line you show mentions. At this point, I suspect the problem is in your existing migrations, and you could try deleting all the unapplied ones (or just move/rename the `app/migrations/XXX_*.py` files so you can replace them if necessary), then run makemigrations, and try to migrate just the newly generated one(s).

Comment: I added the entire message if that helps. If I deleted my migrations would it mess up all the code, and would I also have to delete the _pycache_ files (I'm not sure what they do)? Thanks for the help!

Comment: it's always safe to delete `__pycache__/` dirs or `.pyc` files - tehy'll get re-created the next time you run any program that uses them. Ideally you'd only move/delete the unapplied migration files. It might be the 8 unapplied ones your error mentions, but those could be system ones too. `./manage.py showmigrations` might tell you which of yours need applied, and you can just delete/move those ones.